# Regular expression to a whole data frame column

Tags: regex, python-3.x, dataframe

I need help with my code.

So right now the code below works for a string.

What I have to achieve is to be able to make this same process but to a whole data frame column which contains descriptions of apartments(df['description']).

The regular expression look for 'ROOMS' and brings the space and the word before the match.

I guess I could achieve this with a **for** function but I don't know how to.

The expected Out should bring the group and match from the regular expression for each row of the column **description** of my df.

Thanks for your help!

---

```
In: mystring = 'VERY BIG 2 ROOMS APARTMENT'
mystring

Out: 'VERY BIG 2 ROOMS APARTMENT'

In:regex = r"\w+(?=\s(ROOMS)\b)"

matches = re.finditer(regex, mystring)

In:for m in re.finditer(r"\w+(?=\s(ROOMS)\b)", mystring): 
    print((m.group(0)+' '+m.group(1)))

Out: 2 ROOMS
```

Comment: So can you give us an example of what the data within the columns looks like? It should still be text right? If so can you cast it to a string?

Comment: dataframe has the attribute `replace` which you can use to capture all the information you need

Comment: @emsimpson92 the data within the columns are strings like the example shown under mystring.

Comment: @Onyambu I have played with replace a bit but couldn't manage to solve my problem. Will keep trying.

Comment: You can give an example of your data, df.head()

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding what exactly you want. Is "2 rooms" not the correct output?

Comment: try `df['column of interest'].replace(regex = r'.*?(\w+\sROOMS).*',value=r'\1')`

Comment: @emsimpson92 The output is correct, I need to store that value in a new column for each row.

Comment: @Onyambu the thing is that the data frame has strings in Spanish. The column df['description'] contains descriptions of properties. The column df['rooms'] has a lot of missing data, which I am trying to correct by finding the number of rooms in the df['description']. Ill try the proposed solution.

Comment: How do you expect us to know what you are dealing with unless you provide a simple example of the problem you are facing and the solution that you need? You need to give an input and output if at all you need help form SO

Comment: try just `\w+\s+ROOMS\b`